# Do inline lambdas suffer the same latency of function pointer indirect addressing

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

```
// approach 1
template <typename T>
void f1(T t, int a, int b) {
   t(a, b);
}

// approach 2
void f2(void(*g)(int, int), int a, int b) 
{
   g(a, b); 
}

void g (int a, int b) 
{
    // do something
}

int main() 
{
   f1([](int a, int b)
         { 
           //do something 
         }, 1, 2);

   f2(&g, 1, 2);
}
```

My question is, do `f1` and `f2` suffer from the same indirect addressing latency to get the address of the function to be executed (given that the lambda is implemented as a function object)?

What if the lambda was not inline?

Note: I declared the function f1 as template to leave the deduction of the parameter lambda type to the compiler (instead of enforcing an std function for example, not sure if it makes a difference though).

Comment: A decent compiler should inline the code directly into the function for a lambda or a functor.

Comment: I'm talking conceptually. Because maybe f1 or f1 can be called inside loops/nested loops.

Comment: If your code is corrected to actually accept the lambda, it could be and probably would be inlined (even into the body of a loop).

Comment: @StoryTeller parameter name added and call corrected, if thats your point

Comment: You never know what the compiler will do. But lambdas are slightly more expensive than function pointers because, optimising aside, they are implemented as function pointer plus closure. The closure (capture list) has to be set up and destroyed. However you also need to do the same manually with function pointers to avoid globals.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean *they are implemented as function pointer plus closure* What?  A lambda is just a easy way to write an unnamed class that has a overloaded `operator()`.  The provide an implicit conversion to a function pointer (when they do not capture) but they are not a function pointer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conceptually the compiler should be able to inline the lambda body.  Using a lambda is a compile time thing, that means the compiler knows exactly what function you are going to call and thus it should be able to inline the code.  With a function pointer the function passed is not really known until run time so the compiler has much more work to do to try and see if can inline it.  Generally the code is not inlined and you have an indirection through the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

> does f1 and f2 suffer from the same indirect addressing latency to get the address of the function to be executed (given that the lambda is implemented as a function object)?

The standard doesn't specify any guarantees about latencies. But there isn't any reason the lambda call to have any more latency than a call to a regular inline function. It is possible for the compiler to determine the address of the generated function at compile time, and no indirection is necessary.

Calling a function pointer may require overhead from the indirection, unless the function has been expanded inline in which case the value of the pointer may be known at compile time in the expanded context.

> what if the lambda was not inline?

You cannot declare a lambda, and define it in another compilation unit. All lambdas are inline.

> Note: I declared the function f1 as template to leave the deduction of the parameter lambda type to the compiler (instead of enforcing an std function for example, not sure if it makes a difference though).

`std::function` has at least as much overhead as a function pointer does.

Comment: but regarding the indirect latencies, there is no difference between capturing and non capturing lambdas?

Comment: @mkmostafa I thought about it and I think not. A capturing lambda will be slightly more expensive to copy into the parameter, but has no effect on the indirection of the call.